# Como verificar se existe um valor específico (string) numa lista em C#?

Tags: c#, .net, razor

Estou tentando montar um input select multiple e deixar marcado as opções que já estiverem presentes numa determinada lista.

Sou iniciante em C# então a lógica do que eu preciso seria mais ou menos essa: (Notem que estou usando Razor)

**Desculpe quem já respondeu. Eu transcrevi o código errado. Corrigi agora:**

```
 foreach (var cc in Model.DdlCentroCusto)
 {
     if (listaCentrosDeCustoEquipe[].CodCentroCusto == cc.Value)
     {
         <option value="@cc.Value" selected="selected">@cc.Text</option>
     }
     else
     {
         <option value="@cc.Value">@cc.Text</option>
     }
 }
```

Isso não funciona pois não especifiquei o index do item, e podem ser varios itens. Eu já vi algum código where relacionado a listas, vi tb que para lista existe uma opção Contains(só que eu preciso ir no campo especifico e pegar pela string e ele pede o tipo do objeto), mas não sei qual devo usar e nem sei como usar.

Creio que não seja dificil então uma ajuda será muito bem vinda.

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach (var itemw in listaCentrosDeCustoEquipe)
 {
     if (itemw.CodCentroCusto == cc.Value)
     {
         <option value="@cc.Value" selected="selected">@cc.Text</option>
     }
     else
     {
         <option value="@cc.Value">@cc.Text</option>
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Consegui solucionar o meu problema:

```
  @foreach (var cc in Model.DdlCentroCusto)
  {
     if (listaCentrosDeCustoEquipe.Where(x => x.CodCentroCusto.ToString() == cc.Value).Count() > 0)
     {
        <option value="@cc.Value" selected="selected">@cc.Text</option>
     }
     else
     {
         <option value="@cc.Value">@cc.Text</option>
     }
  }
```

Faço um filtro na lista para que ela fique apenas com valores iguais ao item atual do foreach, se a lista trouxer mais de um resultado é porque esse item está na lista e ai eu marco ele no meu select.

Comment: Não use Where por que ele vai iterar a lista inteira. Use Any(). Ex: listaCentrosDeCustoEquipe.Any(x => x.CentroCusto.ToString() == cc.Value)

Comment: Ótima dica. Nesse caso a lista terá no máximo 5 itens mas utilizarei!

Answer (score 1):

```
@Html.DropDownList("MeuSelect", listaCentrosDeCustoEquipe.Select(option => new SelectListItem
   {
       Text = option.CodCentroCusto,
       Value = option.CodCentroCusto.ToString(),
       Selected = option.CodCentroCusto == cc.Value)
   }));
```

Comment: Não vou testar pois o meu já esta funcionando, mas parece uma ótima solução. +1.